# Contains returning false for two identical objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, contains, assertion, assertthat

I have a MetroStop class as below:

```
public class MetroStop {
public int identifiant;
public double longitude;
public double latitude;
public String nom;
public String destination;
public String moyen;

public MetroStop() {
    
}

public MetroStop(int identifiant, double longitude, double latitude, String nom, String destination, String moyen) {
    this.identifiant = identifiant;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.moyen = moyen;
}
```

I read from a file with the following format:

```
11339855#2.39216908162993#48.7905387877103#AUDIGEOIS#VITRY-SUR-SEINE#bus
```

From this file's lines I create MetroStop objects and add them to an ArrayList.
After adding all the objects, I do the following assertion to verify if a specific object is in the list.

```
 MetroStop testMetro = new MetroStop(446306, 2.40895224652756, 48.8674280733386, "SEVERINE", "PARIS-20EME", "tram");
    assertThat(teste.listeArrets.contains(testMetro), is(true));
```

The testMetro object is created from the data of a random line in the file, thus I am sure that the list contains it. I have also printed all the elements of the list and I could see the exact same object as testMetro, but the assertion is false because contains returns false. Can you please help me to understand why do I get false?
Thank you!

Comment: Does your class implement `equals`?

Comment: No MetroStop does not implement equals. Is this the issue?

Comment: Yes. Your list does not know that your two objects are equal if you haven't written the equals method to tell it that they are.

Comment: @khelwood yeah right, I totally forgot about it. thank u a lot